# Entity Framework: How to map an entity's property to a stored proc?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have the below entity:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int Data {get; set;}
}
```

where `Id` is the primary key and `Data` field is retrieved from a stored proc. The stored proc computes its result based on `MyEntity.Id` field, i.e. it takes `MyEntity.Id` as an argument like this: `GetDataForMyEntity(@MyEntityId)`. I'm using EF Code First approach. How should I set up my EntityTypeConfiguration so that the above is achieved?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then `MyEntity` is not an entity (it is not saved inside database), it represents a data than needs to be computed using stored procedure.

Your code should looks like this:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int Data {
        get {
            using(var context = new DatabaseContext())
            {   
                var idParam = new SqlParameter("@MyEntityId", Id);

                return context.Database
                    .SqlQuery<int>("GetDataForMyEntity @MyEntityId", idParam).SingleOrDefault();
            }
        };

        // Data should not have a setter!!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the heading "Importing Stored Procedures that Return Entities" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx